Why does this attribute selection not return a value?
I need to use a dictionary of sorts in XSLT so that when given a key I can get back a value. I know that there are more formal ways to do this, but they are unrelated to my question.
When given the following XML:
<Root>
    <Entry>
        <Number>123456</Number>
        <Key>1</Key>
    </Entry>
</Root>

And applying the following transform:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"
                byte-order-mark="yes"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
                
    <xsl:variable name="myDictionary"
                  as="element()">
        <dictionary>
            <entry key="1">A</entry>
            <entry key="2">B</entry>
            <entry key="3">C</entry>
            <entry key="4">D</entry>
            <entry key="5">E</entry>
            <entry key="6">F</entry>
            <entry key="7">G</entry>
            <entry key="8">H</entry>
            <entry key="9">I</entry>
            <entry key="10">J</entry>
            <entry key="11">K</entry>
            <entry key="12">L</entry>
            <entry key="13">M</entry>
            <entry key="14">N</entry>
            <entry key="15">O</entry>
        </dictionary>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Entry"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Entry">
        <!-- Employee Identifier -->
        <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Key"/>
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$myDictionary/entry[@key=Key]"/>
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$myDictionary/entry[@key='1']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

I expect to get the following output:
123456 : 1 : A : A

What I actually get instead is baffling:
﻿123456 : 1 :  : A

In the actual output, I can see that <xsl:value-of select="Key"/> shows that it contains the value I expect it to: 1
The last value-of also behaves as I expect: when selecting from the entry elements the one that has an attribute matching 1, I get the value I expect: A.
So why don't I get any value back in the 3rd value-of statement? Since Key contains 1 and 1 matches to the entry containing A, I should get A... yes?
Any suggestions why this isn't working the way I expect? I'm using XSLT 2.0, btw.
(incidentally, I'm also investigating how to PROPERLY use the key() function in XSLT, which may solve the problem, but I also want to know the answer to the above puzzle).

this statement:
<xsl:value-of select="$myDictionary/entry[@key=Key]"/>

will compare a element Key of entry (xpath: entry/Key) that is not there.
Just change it to:
<xsl:value-of select="$myDictionary/entry[@key=current()/Key]"/>

It will use the template-context.
Or another option would be, to first store that Key in a variable and use it like this:
<xsl:template match="Entry">
  <!-- Employee Identifier -->
  <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
  <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Key"/>
  <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
  <!-- Key value of Entry -->
  <xsl:variable name="key" select="Key"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$myDictionary/entry[@key= $key]"/>
  <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$myDictionary/entry[@key='1']"/>
</xsl:template>


OOH!! That makes sense. Context is hard to keep track of sometimes... Thanks!

For completion, you could use a key like this:
<xsl:variable name="myDictionary">
        <entry key="1">A</entry>
        <entry key="2">B</entry>
        <entry key="3">C</entry>
        <entry key="4">D</entry>
        <entry key="5">E</entry>
        <entry key="6">F</entry>
        <entry key="7">G</entry>
        <entry key="8">H</entry>
        <entry key="9">I</entry>
        <entry key="10">J</entry>
        <entry key="11">K</entry>
        <entry key="12">L</entry>
        <entry key="13">M</entry>
        <entry key="14">N</entry>
        <entry key="15">O</entry>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="entry-key" match="entry" use="@key"/>
...
    <xsl:value-of select="key('entry-key', Key, $myDictionary)"/>
...

